# How to import public and protected overloads only into a derived class scope?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to import into a derived class scope the `public` and `protected` overloads of a given function *only*, that is, without trying to import the `private` overloads?

Minimal example:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
  private: void foo(int) {};
  public: void foo(double) {};
};

template<class U>
struct B : A<U> {
  using A::foo; // <- error: tries to import _all_ foo overloads (one is private)

  // want to use foo here without writing A<U>::foo (or an alias for A), or
  // this->foo,
  // all the time
};
```

Comment: What are you ACTUALLY trying to solve (in other words, why do you have a `private` method with the same name as a public one - can't you rename it, given that it's private and thus can't be called from anywhere else)?

Comment: The private method is a modifying non-const operation which is fine (and necessary) for the class internal implementation. The public one is a read-only operation. I could give them two different names but conceptually they do the same thing and const-overloading picks up the right one anyways so within that class it doesn't make sense to give them different names. Giving them different names just for making the life of people deriving from my class easier seems thus like a workaround since within the class itself two different names do not make sense.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is any other workaround - but I'm happy to be wrong on that.

Comment: Hmm... it doesn't work for member functions, however, it does work for constructors.